# Apache Airflow authentication not able to create user

Tags: python, airflow

In Airflow not able to create user getting error

> psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known

How to resolve this error?

Comment: hostname should be the address of the db not the username. Your connection string is incorrect. Can you share how you're connecting to the db?

Comment: Thanks @ Daniel Lee now its working